# Full Calendar 4 day agenda view

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using fullcalendar script for my app. It currently allows to choose one from following views: month, basicWeek, basicDay, agendaWeek, and  agendaDay ( http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/views/Available_Views/ ). I wonder if there is a possibility to modify it to display a 3 or 4-day Agenda view. Any tips for modifications will be helpful!

Comment: This has been requested, and there are some tentative solutions around:
[1314]http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=1314
[1377]http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=1377&can=1&q=sunday&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Milestone%20Summary%20Stars

Answer (score 2):

There was an update in version 2.2.5 of Full Calendar that allows this kind of customization.

This can now be done with something like this:

```
views: {
  agendaThreeDay: {
    type: 'agenda',
    duration: { days: 3 },
    buttonText: '3 day'
  },
  defaultView: 'agendaThreeDay'
}
```

If you want it to display a four calendar day change the duration to 4. You can get more information on this from the document page on [Custom Views](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Custom_Views/).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the `hiddenDays` option, see http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/hiddenDays/ for details.